# What are interfaces when viewing vnstat data?

Tags: monitoring

I'm trying out vnstat.  I can see rx (recieved) and tx (transmitted) data counts for two interfaces.  Simple enough.  But what are the interfaces?  how can I look up what service they represent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ip` or `ifconfig` These commands will give you detailed information about each interface, including its type, IP address, and other relevant information.

In a terminal:

`ip addr show` will give the ip addresses associated with the interfaces

`ifconfig` will give you your available interfaces